# Calculation of backpropagation of a NN with skip nodes

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

Assume this neural net.

[image: MLP]

In our course we had to provide the forward and backward pass for this net. This is the solution we received:

[image: Caclulation]

Even with the solutions provided I still have problems understanding the steps taken to get through the backward pass. Especially the step $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}$ where the partial derivative of the skip node comes together is a mystery to me. Our Profs do not go in detail of the algorithm. Especially if the partial is shortened it yields a contradiction, right? Or does this simply not matter since the gradient is a vector?

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}&=
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_1}\cdot\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial z_0}+
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a_2}\cdot\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial z_0}\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}&=
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}&\stackrel{!}{=}2\cdot\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_0}\\
\end{align}

Wheres my fallacy?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Where are these pictures from?

Comment: Thank you. From our exercises. Is this not allowed?

Comment: It is allowed, but could you post a link.

Comment: The exercises are on a closed platform of our university.

Comment: Why the downvotes?